# Is there a way to find out what process wrote to a file?

Tags: linux, fedora-17

The file `/sys/devices/platform/samsung/leds/samsung::kbd_backlight/brightness` gets written to by some process each time the screen wakes up from being blank.

Is there a way to find out which process writes to this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, my initial thought was to use `inotify` a la [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki), but it seems that is **impossible**, because "The inotify API provides no information about the user or process that triggered the inotify event." ([source](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify)) Sometimes it's helpful to know what **won't** work, too, so here it is.

`fanotify` is a separate, competing notify framework for Linux, which is *newer* and *more robust*, and the API **does** contain information about the process ID (pid) of the program that did the event.

I'm not sure if Fedora 17 has a `fanotify` command built in (or similar). If not, you can see a sample fanotify program [here](http://git.infradead.org/users/eparis/fanotify-example.git). It **does** print out the Process ID (pid) of the process that did the event, so you can compile that program (if it's still compatible with the latest fanotify ABI on Fedora 17) and run it and it should work. See line 231 of [this](http://git.infradead.org/users/eparis/fanotify-example.git/blob/HEAD:/fanotify.c) file.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, fanotify does work! It turns out upowerd is messing with the keyboard backlight brightness.